# In terms of HTTP request performance, AJAX or Flash?

Tags: ajax, flash

In terms of HTTP request performance should I pick AJAX or Flash? To be more specific, I'm more into Flash than AJAX and I'm currently working on a wide scale web project. I wanted to try AJAX out for once and now it's getting too messy for me. Before it gets more complicated I thought may be I can run Flash on the background for HTTP Requests and use it with javascript.

I couldn't find any benchmark on the Internet, but I think AJAX is faster than Flash. So what's your personal experience? Is there too much difference between Flash and AJAX?

Comment: While I'm unsure on generic httprequests, if you have control over the service layer, it is certainly faster to use `amf3` than standard httprequests. There are multiple benefits to this solution from efficient de/serialization to the rpc framework bundling up multiple requests into a single request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flash and JS both use the browser to send HTTP requests so I don't see any reason there would be a difference in performance between them.

Comment: thanks, I see your point. Still, I'm assuming that there is a gap between for Flash and JS to access browser's HTTP request capability. Should I consider this or I can simply ignore?

Comment: Sure! Especially if you are using Javascript to call your Flash...  But unless you are sending HTTPRequest in a frenetic loop, I don't see why the tiny time differences will have an impact or your performances. As @shanethat says, it's negligible.

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, AJAX tends to be a *little* faster than Flash, depending on what movie you're showing. If your movie is extremely large, then it will take longer, but for small content they're virtually as fast; the difference is barely seen. However, keep in mind I'm testing on a fairly good laptop; on other devices and machines, like cellphones, the difference might be bigger (probably flash would be slower).

Hope this helps a bit!
N.S.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that AJAX is a generally faster than Flash performing a similar request, but really the speed difference should be a negligible consideration.  Having the additional requirement of a Flash movie to just act as an HTTP communication tool seems to be a bad idea because you are still going to require a Javascript solution to act where Flash is unavailable.

Comment: in my case flash is already a must and I don't need to consider other platforms like cellphones.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder where the proof is in any of these responses.  I've used both, I started off doing lots of HTML and JS programming and used AJAX when it was first getting traction and found it to be okay with regard to performance.  AMF3 is faster than JSON hands down.  Why?  Not because of differences in the HTTP standards that they both hitch a ride on, but because of the way the data itself is represented (the compressions schemes used and serialization/de-serialization mechanisms make all the difference).

Go ahead and check it out for yourself, http://www.jamesward.com/census2/
(after all the best proof is a test)

Dojo JSON using gzip compression is closest to AMF3 but still produces a payload of about 160% the size of the AMF payload, one and a half times larger is not in my opinion ever going to be faster assuming equivalent bandwidth.  I believe with the latest JavaScript engines the time to de-serialize the data in a browser directly vs having the Flash plugin do that work might make JSON faster for small payloads but when it comes to large amounts of data I don't think that processing time difference would make up for the payload size.